# How to determine whether the app is opened from NotificationCenter (Local Notification) or the app icon when app is killed

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

My App receives a local notification Not a remote Notification. How can I know if the app is opened by pressing the notification and not the app icon when the app is killed( Not running in background or foreground). Previosuly, I used the following method

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if ((launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.loaclNotification] != nil))
    {
        print("here")
    }
 }
```

however this function is deprecated as of iOS 10

```
[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.loaclNotification] != nil)
```

and apple documentation suggests to use the following method.

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
```

}

This method is called only when the app is in the foreground or background. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I know if the app is opened by pressing the notification and not the app icon

As you said, implement the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate method `didReceive`. If the user tapped your notification, it will be called, launching your app if it isn’t running.

Answer (score 0):

One reason of not getting didReceive call after app is killed is not setting delegate on start of the app. In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method delegate must be set

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
 center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
 center.delegate = self
```

}