# Access Notification Payload if application is launched by local notification

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

How can I get notified and access the notification payload if a user clicks on a local notification while the app is in the suspended state and launches the application? 
Whenever my iOS app is opened from the background state the UNNotification response function is called. The local notification launched by key has been deprecated and I can't figure out how to determine if the app has been launched by a local notification. I need to use the notification payload to populate the view controller properly.

I am using this function to get the notification response while the app is in the background state:

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive
        response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
        @escaping () -> Void) {

setup view here using payload
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581191/how-to-determine-whether-the-app-is-opened-from-notificationcenter-local-notifi ? I don't understand what the issue is. `didReceive` is called and now you're off to the races. How is this different from what you were doing before? I'm probably missing something; can you elaborate? Thx

Comment: The function is not called if I force close the app before selecting the notification. If I background the app and click the notification the function implemented is called and works just fine.

Comment: Why isn’t it called? Where do you configure your User Notification Center delegate?

Comment: I wish I knew why. Its driving me nuts. I have the notification center delegate function inside a static class. Should it be in the app delegate?

Comment: It isn’t a matter of where it is but when it is. You need to set some instance as the delegate the moment you launch.

Comment: Would it be easy to give a quick and dirty example of what you mean? Thanks for the help so far

Comment: I think I know what you mean actually. Feel free to answer so I can mark you correct

Comment: Sorry, using mobile. Missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Have a good night man. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are not configuring the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate early enough. You need to do that very early, as in `didFinishLaunching`, so that the runtime knows where to send `didReceive`. This is how I do it:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self.notifHelper
    return true
}
```